# Underfull \hbox in paragraph without indent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, parindent

I try to make a [letter in the colombian's format](https://es.slideshare.net/dianatierradentro/35697938-normaicontecntc3393paracartascomerciales-1) but when I want to add the recipient information without indent I got a `Underfull \hbox` (look the line `Ingeniero`).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%

%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    letterpaper,
    twoside,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    inner=4cm,
    outer=2cm,
    headheight=1.75cm,
    headsep=0.625cm,
}
%

%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{
    \raisebox{-.4\height}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo}}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        xxx\\
        xxx\\ 
        xxx\\
        xxx
    \end{tabular}
}
\cfoot{Página \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}
%

%
\usepackage{fgruler}
\setfgruler{
    color=red,
    showframe,
    % type=lowerright,
}
%

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent \textbf{Referencia}: GUA-EST-00

    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
    \noindent Bogotá D.C., \today

    \vspace*{4\baselineskip}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    Ingeniero\\  % here it's my problem.
    xxx\\
    Gerente General\\
    xxx\\
    xxx\\
    xxx\\

    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \textbf{Asunto:} xxx

    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    Apreciado xxx:

    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
    El día viernes 8 de noviembre recibimos su carta con la cotización de los diseños

\end{document}
```

I already try with \noindent but I got the same error.

Do you have any advice ?

Comment: The problem is the last `xxx\\ ` . Never end a paragraph with `\\ `.

Comment: Yes. I just changed it and works ! Thank you !